# Can you access a class name in a VSCode snippet?

Tags: textmate, visual-studio-code

For instance, how would you create the equivalent of the `ctor` Visual Studio C# snippet in VSCode?  I'm looking through the TextMate docs, which the VSCode snippet system is based on and I see lots of variables like TM_SCOPE but VSCode seems to be not evaluating these variables.  Is this impossible in the current state of VSCode snippet support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the VSCode documentation, when you want to create a new snippets file for C# :

```
// Place your snippets for C# here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
// description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
// $1, $2 for tab stops, ${id} and ${id:label} and ${1:label} for variables. Variables with the same id are connected.
```

It seems that currently (on v0.10.6), only $n variables are allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't particularly optimistic that this would be supported.

Comment: For future readers, VSCode includes a new variable [`TM_FILENAME_BASE`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets): `public static displayName: string = \"${TM_FILENAME_BASE}\";`.

Answer (score 4):

It does however support all TextMate vars excluding Interpolation Templates, RegEx, and Transformations -- so you can do one for adding based on file name:

```
"body": [
    "public $TM_FILENAME()",
    "{",
    "$0",
    "}"
]
```

This unfortunately gets the file extension also, have not figured out how to shave that off yet

Comment: You can use `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` as Carlos Huchim did here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571235/can-you-access-a-class-name-in-a-vscode-snippet#comment92017233_34608222

All variable list here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that nowadays, you can!

Just add ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} were you want the file name to show up. There are a bunch of other variables as well, like TM_CURRENT_LINE for getting the text on the current line, and even CLIPBOARD.

You can find all available commands under the official documentation here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables